# Uniform n-gon subdivision

Tags: language-agnostic

I know how to get the interpolated points on a rectangular grid using bilinear interpolation:

```
def bilinearInterpolation(p1, p2, p3, p4, ratioX, ratioY):
    return (1 - ratioX) * ((1 - ratioY) * p1 +  ratioY * p4) + ratioX * ((1 - ratioY) * p2 +  ratioY * p3)
```

This makes it easy to fill in the points for corners p1..p4 with two nested loops changing ratioX and ratioY. Now, what is the general approach for a n-sided polygon, assuming the segment count is identical for each side (see the picture)?

[image]